# ComboBox disabled with C# enable with js

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, combobox

I have an ASPxComboBox which is disabled via C# code and I want to enable it with js Code, but sadly it doesn't work.

Here is what I do:
At first I disable it

```
comboBox.Enabled = false;
```

Then after a client side selectedItemchanged event is called I call a js function

```
comboBox.SetEnabled(true);
```

There is no problem entering the function and if the comboBox isn't disabled in the C# code it is no problem at all dis-/enabling it via js.

Is there a different way how I should approach this?

EDIT:
I create the ASPxComboBox hardcoded like this

```
ASPxComboBox comboBox = new ASPxComboBox();
```

then I add the clientInstancename to have acces via js code (and ID)

```
comboBox.ID= "comboBox";
comboBox.ClientInstanceName = comboBox.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this >

```
$("#comboBox").attr("enabled", true);  // To enabled

$("#comboBox").attr("disabled", true); // To disabled
```

**OR**

```
document.getElementById("comboBox").enabled = true; // To enabled 

document.getElementById("comboBox").disabled = true;// To disabled
```

**Edit**
For `ASPxComboBox` , you should use `SetEnabled()` .

```
document.getElementById("comboBox").SetEnabled(true);
document.getElementById("comboBox").SetEnabled(false);
```

Reference this [How to enable / disable controls on the client side via javascript](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q292696) and [ASPxClientEditBase.SetEnabled Method](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsScriptsASPxClientEditBase_SetEnabledtopic) .

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, but it still doesn't work.
The js script stops working at the point I try to do it like this. Is it because I create the ASPxComboBox hardcoded?

Comment: Can you show me how did you create ComboBox in Codebehind ? Have you set the ID of your ComboBox ?

Comment: Is that DevExpress comboBox ?

Comment: Yes I am 100% sure it is.

Comment: Can you get the value of comboBox ? Check it by msg Box , `alert(document.getElementById("comboBox").Text);`

Comment: No it didn't alert, at this point the js script stopped working. It only works when I acces it through its clientinstancename.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use C#:

```
void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
}
protected void comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged (object sender, eventargs e)
{
    comboBox.Enabled = true;
}
```

**OR**
use JQuery:

```
$('#<%= comboBox.ClientID %>').change(function() {
        $(this).attr("disabled", false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can't use a C# event because then a Postback would be needed that refreshes the whole site. To prevent this I access a js script on the server.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
$('#<%= comboBox.ClientID %>').removeAttr("disabled");
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, but as I said to @zey it still doesn't work. The js script stops working at the point I try to do it like this. Is it because I create the ASPxComboBox hardcoded?